# Endorser Missing Blocks

Tags: error

I recently setup a node and started endorsing and baked my first block, after I baked my first block it showed no future baking rights but continued endorsing for a few weeks then the endorse just stopped and I started missing blocks. Nothing changed in my setup, everything is running but nothing shows up in the endorser. I cannot figure out what is wrong and don't know where to start with troubleshooting.

```
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 50837 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: 154 bytes added (will add 20 for safety)
Ledger Application level error (sign-with-hash): Parse error
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
root@bakersrv:/home/baker/tezos#
```

What is a Parse error? I've tried to search and cannot come up with anything

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for that error is if the baking account is in a Ledger and the Ledger is not running the baking app.

If you run `tezos-client list connected ledgers` the output should include something like "Found a Tezos Baking [...] application".